# Importing table dump to Heroku Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I've created a dump file of one table on my local db using `pg_dump` and want to import it to my production db on Heroku to replace the current production version of the table.

I was looking at these instructions: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#import-to-heroku-postgres

Should I use `pg_restore` or can I use `heroku pg:backups:restore`? Does using `heroku pg:backups:restore` drop the entire db and replace it with the contents of the dump file or will it only drop and replace what is in the dump file? I am concerned about data other than what's in the dump file being dropped (since my dump file is only one table). I will of course create a backup of production before doing this, but am curious what the best approach is. Thanks!

Comment: "Note that the pg:backups restore command drops any tables and other database objects before recreating them."

Comment: pg_restore does not however unless you use the `--clean` option.

Comment: I saw that, but does it only drop the tables/db objects that are being replaced, or the entire db?

Comment: "Tables not included in the backup should not be affected" when using `heroku pg:backups:restore` according to: http://jamesdempsey.github.io/blog/2013/07/28/restoring-a-single-postgresql-table-from-heroku-pgbackups/